# Trigger an animation without state change from outside a Composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

In a Composable it is easy to animate between state changes. But is there a good way to just trigger an animation without state change, e.g. let an element blink when there is a signal from outside.

Example:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatableText(play: State<Boolean>) {
    val alpha = remember { Animatable(0f) }

    LaunchedEffect(play.value) {
        alpha.snapTo(0f)
        alpha.animateTo(1f, animationSpec = tween(2000))
    }

    Text(
        text = "TEST",
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(alpha.value)
    )
}
```

In this example, the text disappears and fades in again, when the state of play changes. However, in this example the animation also plays, when the Composable is created. Also, the state of play must change, where it would be nicer to just have a function outside the Composable, where we can just call `play()`. There might be workarounds to avoid animation on creation, but I wonder if there is a simple and reliable way to trigger an animation, which does not reflect a state change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do for example something like this:

```kotlin
class AnimatableTextState(
    initialAlpha: Float = 1F,
) {
    private val animatable = Animatable(initialAlpha)
    val alpha: Float get() = animatable.value

    suspend fun play() {
        animatable.snapTo(0F)
        animatable.animateTo(1F, animationSpec = tween(2000))
    }
}

@Composable
fun AnimatableText(state: AnimatableTextState) {
    Text(
        text = "TEST",
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(state.alpha)
    )
}

@Composable
fun OtherComposable() {
    val animatableTextState = remember { AnimatableTextState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    Column {
        AnimatableText(animatableTextState)
        Button(onClick = { scope.launch { animatableTextState.play() } }) {
            Text("Animate")
        }
    }
}
```

With this, your text will start with `alpha = 1F` and it will only animate when `play()` is called, not after composable is created. If you want to start with different alpha value, you can simple do that `remember { AnimatableTextState(0.5F) }`.

Comment: I wonder, if there is an option to call "play" from outside an composition. It seems that the animatable requires a MonotonicFrameClock in the calling coroutine scope, which is only available within compositions.

Answer (score 0):

> **animateFloatAsState** https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/customize
> As per your need you are trying to animate the text over a float value. also you can control the `mutableState` as as per your need.
> Here is the example. when your view composes for first time it wont animate. but that also you can change easily as you declare as state.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnimatableText(alpha: Float) {
    Text(
        text = "TEST",
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(alpha),
    )
}
@Composable
fun ExampleAnimatableText() {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val alpha by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (state) 1F else 0F,
        animationSpec = tween(
            2000,
        ),
    )
    AnimatableText(alpha)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As far as I understand, your example still animates state changes (between `state=true` and `state=false`). I was trying to avoid that, but just to "play" an animation, which be replayed each time, one calls something like "play".